# Converting Dask Scalar to integer value (or save it to text file)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I have calculated using `dask` by

```
from dask import dataframe
all_data = dataframe.read_csv(path) 
total_sum = all_data.account_balance.sum()
```

The csv file has a column named `account_balance`.

The `total_sum` is a `dd.Scalar` object, which seems to be difficult to change it to integer. How to get the integer version of it? or save it in a `.txt` file containing the number is also ok.

I have also tried `total_sum.compute()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Once you compute it you can print it and/or save to file.

Answer (score 9):

`.compute()` does indeed bring you a real number, as you can see in this example:

```
In [18]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [19]: d = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,3,3,3]}), npartitions=2)

In [20]: d.a.sum().compute()
Out[20]: 12
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there another way? the `total_sum.compute()` takes really long time.

Comment: @anbarief1 dask is lazy it means that if you don't compute it you only have the graph for computation.

Comment: It takes a long time because it has to read all of your CSV data!